# Hard time creating PIVOT in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table

Hi all I am very much confused about how to implement PIVOT in this scenario

```
AccId   Year    Month   AccType     Value
225     2012    7           1       2
225     2012    7           2       0
225     2012    7           3       0
226     2012    7           1       3
226     2012    7           2       0
226     2012    7           3       0
```

The main problem I am not able to solve is AccId is joined with AccountTable and AccType is also joined with AccountType table I need output like this:

```
AccId AccName Year Month AccType AccTypeName Value AccType AccTypeName Value AccType AccTypeName Value
225   ABC     2012  7      1        AAA        2     2         BBB       0      3       CCC    0 
226   ABC     2012  7      1        AAA        3     2         BBB       0      3       CCC    0
```

Any Help please. Thanks.

Comment: where the AccType name came ?

Comment: Join with AccountType Table

Comment: where is the Account Type Table

Comment: AccountTable== AccId (INT) and AccName (Varchar(50)) ===== AND =====
AccountType== AccType (INT) and AccTypeName (Varchar(50))

Comment: please verify the posted answer @tony

Comment: Thanks @mohan111 It is all what I need. But I am not able to understand your solution and I am not able to use it with my actual data.

Comment: what ever the sample data you have provided basing on that I have given solution. But Pivoting is little bit confusing it's upto you to implement in your code @tonys

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
    (AccId int, Year int, Month int, AccType int, Value int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (AccId, Year, Month, AccType, Value)
VALUES
    (225, 2012, 7, 1, 2),
    (225, 2012, 7, 2, 0),
    (225, 2012, 7, 3, 0),
    (226, 2012, 7, 1, 3),
    (226, 2012, 7, 2, 0),
    (226, 2012, 7, 3, 0)
;


DECLARE @Tabletype TABLE 
    (AccId int, Type Varchar(6))
    INSERT INTO @Tabletype
    (AccId,Type )values (225,'AAA'), (226,'BBB')
;
;WITH CTE AS (
Select AccId, Year, Month,1 AS Acct1,2 AS Acct2,3 AS Acct3,Type from (
select T.AccId, T.Year, T.Month,T.AccType,TT.Type,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY T.AccId ORDER BY T.Year,T.month)RN from @Table1 T
INNER JOIN  @Tabletype TT
ON T.AccId = TT.AccId)T
PIVOT(MAX(RN) FOR AccType IN([1],[2],[3]))PVT
GROUP BY AccId, Year, Month,pvt.Type)
, CTE2 AS (
Select AccId, Year, Month,[0] AS val1,[2] AS val2,[3] AS val3,Type from (
select T.AccId, T.Year, T.Month, T.Value,TT.Type,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY T.AccId ORDER BY T.Year,T.month)RN from @Table1 T
INNER JOIN  @Tabletype TT
ON T.AccId = TT.AccId)T
PIVOT(MAX(RN) FOR value IN([0],[2],[3]))PVTt
GROUP BY AccId, Year, Month,PVTt.[0],PVTt.[2],PVTt.[3],PVTt.Type)



select c.AccId,
c.Year,
C.Month,
c.Acct1,
c.Type,
ISNULL(cc.val1,0)val1,
C.Acct2,
c.Type,
ISNULL(CC.val2,0)val2,
C.Acct3,
c.Type,
ISNULL(CC.val3,0)val3 from CTE c
inner join CTE2 cc
on c.AccId = cc.AccId
```